# how to serialize polymorphic to-many Core Data relationship with RestKit?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, serialization, restkit, polymorphic-associations

I need to serialize a Core Data class (`Questionnaire`) which has a to-many relationship (`questions`) to an abstract entity (`Question`).

`Question` is the parent entity for a number of concrete subclasses (`BooleanQuestion`, `ClosedQuestion`…), each of which has an `RKManagedObjectMapping`.

How can I set up the Questionnaire mapping to serialize this polymorphic relationship?

If it was not polymorphic, I would do:

```
[questionnaireMapping mapRelationShip:@"questions" withMapping:[questionMapping inverseMapping]];
```

But I can't do that: questions will not be of any single class, so there isn't a single mapping to pass.

Moreover, Question being abstract, doesn't even have a mapping (though I could define one).

How can I handle that with RestKit version 0.10.3?

Note that I am very close to releasing my product, and I am really reluctant to migrate to RestKit 0.20 this late in my product cycle.

I guess I could aggregate all concrete `Question` subclasses into `Question`, making it concrete and monomorphic (and monolithic). That would be ugly (though I believe this is precisely what Core Data does with SQLite behind the scene).

Anything more elegant?

Thanks

JD

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 0.20 wouldn't help anyway as I don't believe this situation is covered there either.

I would recommend you to implement a method (or just use `KVC`) on each of the classes in the hierarchy which returns a dictionary of the keys and values. This can be done efficiently using `KVC` `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`. The list of keys should be the union of all keys for all classes. Now you can build an array of dictionaries which can be mapped. You would also need to implement `KVC` `-valueForUndefinedKey:` to prevent exceptions during this process.

Now, on your `Questionnaire` class you can implement a method to loop over the `questions` relation contents and build the list of dictionaries. Say the method was called `encodedQuestions`, your mapping would be something like:

```
[questionnaireMapping mapRelationShip:@"encodedQuestions" withMapping:questionDictMapping];
```

I haven't actually tried doing this so there is a question about the reflection RestKit uses on Core Data objects and how happy it will be taking your relation mapping.